# Artificial Neural Network layers

Tags: neural-network

I have decided to try and make a reccognition system. And I want to start with pictures of say, 16x16 pixels. That will be 256 INPUT NEURONS.
Now, the output neurons is essensially how many results I want, so say I want to distinguish the letters A, B and C.
then i need 3 OUTPUT NEURONS right?

My question is, how can I know how many neurons I need in the hidden layer? And what was the purpose of them again? Is it how many character classes I want? Say, O and Q are quite simular, so thay both would lead to one hidden layer neuron who later tell them appart?

Answer (score 2):

You're right about the input and output layers.

> How can I know how many neurons I need in the hidden layer?

There's no concrete rule that says exactly how many units you need in the hidden layers of a neural network. There are some general guidelines though, which I'll quote from [one of my answers on Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/100431/615).

> Number of input units: Dimension of features x(i)
>
> Number of output units: Number of classes
>
> Reasonable default is one hidden layer, or if > 1 hidden layer, have the same number of hidden units in every layer (usually the more the better, anywhere from about 1X to 4X the number of input units).

You also asked:

> And what was the purpose of them again?

The hidden layer units just transform the inputs into values (using coefficients selected during training) that can be used by the output layer.

> Is it how many character classes I want? Say, O and Q are quite similar, so thy both would lead to one hidden layer neuron who later tell them apart?

No, that's not right. The number of output units will be the same as the number of classes you want. Each output unit will correspond to one letter, and will say whether or not the input image is that letter (with some probability). The output unit with the highest probability is the one you select as the right letter.

Comment: I still don't know the theoretical task of the hidden layers. I understand they are there to decrease the likelyhood of errors, but there is 1 neuron for each pixel in the image... How many for neurons for 1 hidden layer in the example I mentioned above?

Comment: @Ledii It's up to you, but each hidden layer should have 1X to 4X the number of input units.